# Alternative Way Running a Timer on NodeJS Using Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to create a reminder app. There should be a DB with table of 'active-reminders'.
There would be a function which will:

1. Identify which reminders reached their time
2. Send a message to the client informing about their set reminder
3. Removing the appropriate reminder from the array

I was thinking about an efficient way to run this function and I thought about:

1. Running this function in an interval of 1 minute that will check for reminders with time due
2. Trigger a setTimeout which will send the appropriate client his reminder - which means for every reminder there would be set up a setTimeout that runs the function as soon as the time is due.

My question:
Is there a better way to implement the solution?
From the methods listed, would you say one of the ways is more efficient that the other one?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Use crontab. Don't rely on nodejs server. It can be restarted for any reason and all callbacks registered with setTimeout are going to be lost.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm trying to stay in the NodeJS brackets(on purpose), what if I create a startup function which will just establish a new pool with the appropriate reminders to be sent? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your appointments are in memory, sort them by trigger time.  If your appointments are in a database, make sure there's an efficient mechanism for accessing the next appointment to reach its time.

Then, using this efficient sorted access mechanism, find the earliest appointment to fire.  If that time has already passed, then fire its notification, remove it from the data structure and repeat.  If that time has not yet passed, set a timer for it's scheduled time.  When that timer fires remove that event from the data structure and repeat the process by getting the next event to fire and setting a timer for it.

Whenever you add a new appointment, check if it's due time is earlier than the one you have a timer for.  If so, release the timer for the one you had and set the timer for the new one.

Whenever an appointment is to be deleted, you first check if it's the next one to notified.  If so, stop its timer and configure the next event.

You can likely do all this with four functions that handle the life cycle changes:

```
addNewEvent(event)        // called when you add a new event to the data
fireEvent(event)          // called when a timer fires to notify of an event
removeEvent(event)        // called when an event is being deleted
configureNextEvent()      // called to configure timer for next event
```

Comment: This! I appreciate your answer, thank you very much sir.

Comment: So sorry, new here. There! Thanks for the tip :)